# How to set Local Notification for input date on Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I am making an app like todo list with Swift, and it has a date column on Realm. I am trying to set the local notification for when the input date is coming. How can I set the trigger from realm data? I would appreciate if you could help me.

--update--
I want to be notified of an upcoming event - like the app tells the user they have an appointment in a week.

Comment: This is pretty vague. What does 'when the input date is coming' mean? Are you stating you want to be notified of an upcoming event - something like your app telling the user they have an appointment in three days? Can you clarify the question by updating it with more and clearer information?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I added information like you said.

Comment: You should take a look at [Triggers](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/) as it is something available via the MongDB Realm server and can trigger recurring events.

Comment: That sounds great, but I've never heard of that. I'll look up if I can switch DB from Realm to the MongDB Realm easily.

Comment: If your not aware, Realm is now a depreciated product as Realm is now owned and managed by MongoDB - the product is MongoDB Realm. You should be transitioning to the new platform at this time.

Comment: Oh, okay. I'm a beginner so I don't know anything about that. I'll study how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is directly possible with Realm, alone. However you can just schedule the notification based off the date entered into the database.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app

Just use:

```
// Configure the recurring date.
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

dateComponents.weekday = 3  // Tuesday
dateComponents.hour = 14    // 14:00 hours
   
// Create the trigger as a repeating event.    
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
         dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I'm trying to use it.

Comment: Great answer and is one possible solution but Realm does offer Triggers (from the server) - see my comment to the question